# Yocto multiple Kernel packages

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build an image which has linux-intel as the the virtual/kernel set. I want to inherit the same kernel recipe as require xxx.bb in my another kernel recipe. Essentially both kernels are same but the 2nd recipe has one extra cfg.

The second kernel recipe has "kernel_package_name" set to its ${PN}. I included this ${PN} in my image bb file by adding it to IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND. But now both of the kernel recipes are trying to install the same files(Strangely it clashes when installing bzimage) I tried using RDEPENDS_kernel-base = "" but no effect.

Please suggest me the best way to install the 2nd kernel into the image without removing the virtual/kernel which is set to 1st kernel.

Comment: Why do you want two kernels to be built with Yocto? What's the usecase?

Comment: @qschulz I want to build the same kernel with and without debug configurations enabled. This config is supplied as a .cfg file